# Haskell catch handling

Tags: haskell, integer, try-catch

I used the code below to catch a read error, while inputting an `Integer` using `getLine`.
The problem is I have to print the integer unnecessarily to match the expected output of function.  As shown in the *catch* statement below in the `checkInt` function. Please let me know what modifications I have to make to avoid `print` ing the integer in the catch block.

```
showError= do 
   putStrLn("ERR")
   exitSuccess


checkInt str = do
  catch (print(read str :: Int)) handler
     where
       handler :: SomeException -> IO ()
    handler ex = showError
```

Comment: Exceptions are _not_ really idiomatic in Haskell. While you're still learning the language, better avoid them entirely. Exceptions generally aren't necessary, because Haskell has very nice support for “partial types” – instead of writing a function that returns a `Result` but might raise an exception, write a function that returns a `Maybe Result`. — To answer your question, it would be helpful to know what you're actually trying to achieve... what is your program supposed to do, for some example inputs?

Answer (score 2):

of course @leftaroundabout is right but I think it might be interesting to see how you can get it working anyways.

you don't have to print it - you just have to enforce evaluation (which you can do here using [`seq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:seq):

```
checkInt :: String -> IO ()
checkInt str =
  catch (seq (read str :: Int) $ return ()) showError

showError :: SomeException -> IO ()
showError _ =
   putStrLn("ERR")
```

example:

```
λ> checkInt "33"
λ> checkInt "ad"
ERR
```

---

of course it might be better to not only check but also return the `Int`:

```
checkInt :: String -> IO Int
checkInt str =
  catch (let i = read str in seq i $ return i) showError

showError :: SomeException -> IO Int
showError _ = do 
   putStrLn("ERR")
   return (-1)
```

example:

```
λ> checkInt "33"
33
λ> checkInt "a3"
ERR
-1
λ> i <- checkInt "a3"
ERR
```

---

### making the function pure

anyways you should heed @leftaroundabouts advice and one possibility would be using [`reads`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:reads) which allows for more flexibility then `read`:

```
checkInt :: String -> Maybe Int
checkInt str =
  case reads str of
     ((i, _):_) -> Just i
     _          -> Nothing
```

example:

```
λ> checkInt "33"
Just 33
λ> checkInt "ab"
Nothing
λ> checkInt "33a77"
Just 33
```

if you don't like the behavior shown in the last example you can change the function to:

```
checkInt :: String -> Maybe Int
checkInt str =
  case reads str of
     [(i, [])] -> Just i
     _         -> Nothing
```

and it should only parse inputs where the complete string can be parsed as an integer:

```
λ> checkInt "33"
Just 33
λ> checkInt "ab"
Nothing
λ> checkInt "33a77"
Nothing
λ> checkInt "33 77"
Nothing
```

Comment: Also there are functions in the base to deal with this: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe